# Returning lines from a JSON log file which contain IP and timestamps read from a CSV file?

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv, json, join

so I'm new to Shell Scripting and could use some help. So in my CSV file, I want to see if IP and timestamp values exists in some way in the line entries of the JSON log file, and if so, return that specific JSON log entry to another file. I tried to make it universal so it's applicable to all IP addresses. Here's what the sample CSV file would look like;

```
"clientip,""destip","dest_hostname","timestamp"
 "127.0.0.1","0.0.0.0","randomhost","2023-09-09T04:18:22.542Z"
```

A sample line entry from the Json Log File

```
{"log": "09-Sept-2023 rate-limit: info: client @xyz 127.0.0.1, "stream":"stderr", "time": 2023-09-09T04:18:22.542Z"}
```

It's the lines from the JSON log file we want to return in the output.txt file when there's a match. The JSON file doesn't have the same fields and organization like the CSV does (with clientip, destip, dest_hostname, timestamp, but I was hoping that I could still at least return lines from the JSON log files to a new file that had matches on the clientip (like we see here with 127.0.0.1 in "info: client @xyz 127.0.0.1) and maybe the timestamp.

I've tried `join file.csv xyz-json.log > output.txt`
I've also tried the `awk` command to  no avail. I would really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: You seem to have a quoting error in the first field's header in the CSV data.  Is that a typo, or is it intentional?  Also, there appears to be a space character before the first field in the actual data.

Comment: The JSON data is also broken, presumably with a missing double quote after the value of the `log` key, and at the start of the `time` keys value.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two input files, `file.csv` and `file.jsonl`, are correctly formatted as CSV and JSONL files, respectively, we can use Miller (`mlr`) to extract the client IP from the value of the `log` key in the JSONL file, and then join the two sets of data using this as the key.

The two test input files (note that the quotes in the CSV file are optional in this instance):

```
"clientip","destip","dest_hostname","timestamp"
"127.0.0.1","0.0.0.0","randomhost","2023-09-09T04:18:22.542Z"
```

```json
{"log": "09-Sept-2023 rate-limit: info: client @xyz 127.0.0.1", "stream": "stderr", "time": "2023-09-09T04:18:22.542Z"}
```

The command:

```bash
mlr --jsonl --from file.jsonl \
    put '$clientip = splita($log," ")[-1]' then \
    join -f file.csv -i csv -j clientip then \
    cut -f log,stream,time
```

This first creates a `clientip` field in the JSONL data by splitting the `log` field's value on spaces and picking out the last word.  It then performs a relational *inner join* operation with the JSONL data as the "right" data set and the CSV data as the "left" data set.  The join is performed with `clientip` as the join key.

At the end, we remove all the fields not originally in the JSONL data from the records resulting from the join (the first two steps both add keys to the data).

Would you want to also use the time stamps from the two files in the join key, then, since the fields have different names in the two data sets, the easiest way to do that would be, I think, to create a `timestamp` key with the value of the `time` key in the JSONL data (basically, you duplicate the `time` data with a new name) and then join like this:

```bash
mlr --jsonl --from file.jsonl \
    put '$clientip = splita($log," ")[-1]; $timestamp = $time' then \
    join -f file.csv -i csv -j clientip,timestamp then \
    cut -f log,stream,time
```

The output from either of the two commands above could be redirected to a file and would, given the (corrected) data in the question, be identical to the JSONL input data.